# Autocompletetext и Sqlite

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос.  Есть текстовое поле с автозаполнением и возможностью редактирования вводимого текста. Автозаполнение идет из базы данных. Но я никак не могу, сделать так, чтобы появлялись не все записи из базы данных, а только относящиеся к вводимому в поле тексту.
Файл MainActivity:

```
      final AutoCompleteTextView Search = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
     int[] to = new int[]{android.R.layout.select_dialog_item};
     mCursor = managedQuery(
                           NameProvider.CONTENT_URI, mContent, null, null, null);
     SimpleCursorAdapter scaComments = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.auto_complete_item,
                   mCursor,new String[] {NameDbHelper.NAME},new int[]{R.id.text1});
    scaComments.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorConverter());
    Search.setAdapter(scaComments);

    scaComments.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider(){

      public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) 
        {

    Cursor cursor = NameDbHelper.getMatchingStates((constraint != null ? constraint.toString() : null));
                    return cursor;
                    }
                    });
```

И файл NameDbHelper

```
 public class NameDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "names";
public static final String NAME = "name";

private static SQLiteDatabase db;
public NameDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NameProvider.DB_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME 
            + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
            + NAME + " TEXT);");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public static Cursor getMatchingStates(String constraint) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "NAME"}, "constraint like " + "'%"+constraint+"%'", null, null, null, null);
    }
```

}

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка ?

Предполагаю, что ошибка в

```
       return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "NAME"}, "constraint like " + "'%"+constraint+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "NAME"}, "NAME like " + "'%"+constraint+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

В обычном SQL это будет аналогично запросу:

```
select name from NAMES where name like '%constraint%'
```

А вообще лучше написать:

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "NAME"}, "NAME like ?", new String[]{ "'%"+constraint+"%'"}, null, null, null);
```

Будет работать быстрее, поскольку конструкция с "?" предполагает прекомпиляцию выражения на стороне SQLite при первом выполнении